# How to plot rect in log scale?

Tags: r

```
R> plot(c(100, 200), c(10, 1000), type= 'n', xlab = '', ylab = '', log='y')
R> rect(110, log(20), 175, log(500), density = 5, border = 'red')
Warning message:
In polygon.fullhatch(xy$x[start:(end - 1)], xy$y[start:(end - 1)],  :
  cannot hatch with logarithmic scale active
```

I tried to plot rect with log scale in y-axis. But it prints this error. I don't see how to specify log scale in y-axis in the help page of `rect()`.

https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/rect.html

How to plot a rectangle in log scale in y-axis?

Comment: it's just a warning, and it doesn't show up because it is out of range on your plot

Comment: OK. But I obviously does not want to draw something that can not been seen. How to draw a rectangle spanning 20 and 500 in the y axis (log-scale)?

Comment: To reiterate, you set up a plotting device where the minimum y value is 10. Then you try to add a rectangle where `ybottom` is `log(20)`, which is `<10` ("out of range on your plot"). Choose appropriate limits of your plot before adding the rectangle. The _warning_ refers to the use of `density` which "is only implemented for linear plots: if either axis is on log scale then shading is omitted"